# gradle: running mvn install on a third part source, inside gradle

Tags: groovy, maven, gradle

i'm trying to use gradle to install and configure all my project enviroment (for example: installing tomcat)

So, now I need to do something like this:

1. download X project (ready)
2. do some config stuff (ready)
3. run "mvn clean install" on the project dir

How can I do the 3rd item?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i figured it out, I can use ant.exec to do that:

```
 ant.exec(outputproperty:"cmdOut", executable: 'mvn', dir: 'projectName') {
        arg(line: 'clean install)
 }
```